# Matching the root URL not working in Pyramid

Tags: pyramid, pylons

According to the [official documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid//en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#matching-the-root-url),
setting

> config.add_route('root', '')

or

> config.add_route('root', '/')

is supposed to take me to the root URL. I set this in my `__init__`.py. 
I want my root to be at www.hello.com/language.

I have

> config.include('.view', route_prefix='/language')

in my project's `__init__`.py

I also have a view configured

> @view_config(route_name='root', renderer='template.jinja2')

in views.py

But, when I go to www.hello.com/language, I get a 404 not found.
What could be the issue?

Comment: It's little bit unclear what you are trying to do? What's `blah`? Do you have a template file in place? Have you tried Pyramid not found debugging setting `pyramid.debug_notfound`?  http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid//en/latest/narr/viewconfig.html#notfound-errors

Answer (score 0):

It will be available at http://www.hello.com/language/. URL + trailing slash.
Perhaps you should look this issue https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues/406

And for more understanding you can control your routes with command:

```shall
$ proutes development.ini 
Name                             Pattern                                 View                                Method      
----                             -------                                 ----                                ------      
__admin/sacrud_deform_static/    /admin/sacrud_deform_static/*subpath    sacrud_deform:static/               *           
__admin/deform_static/           /admin/deform_static/*subpath           deform:static/                      *           
__admin/sa_static/               /admin/sa_static/*subpath               pyramid_sacrud:static/              *           
pyramid_sacrud_home              /admin/                                 pyramid_sacrud.views.sa_home        *           
pyramid_sacrud_list              /admin/{table}/                         pyramid_sacrud.views.CRUD.List      GET         
pyramid_sacrud_create            /admin/{table}/create/                  pyramid_sacrud.views.CRUD.Add       GET,POST    
pyramid_sacrud_update            /admin/{table}/update/*pk               pyramid_sacrud.views.CRUD.Add       GET,POST    
pyramid_sacrud_delete            /admin/{table}/delete/*pk               pyramid_sacrud.views.CRUD.Delete    GET         
pyramid_sacrud_mass_action       /admin/{table}/action/                  pyramid_sacrud.views.CRUD.Action    POST
```

Comment: The correct patterns and corresponding views show up, but when I go to URL + trailing trash, I get a 404 error, even though there is a view callable with the renderer in place

Comment: I deleted my answer, as it was unrelated to `route_prefix` which is where the problem is. Looks like there's a pull request to fix this, so until they do that, what you're trying to do won't work.